# Avoiding race conditions in Google Analytics asynchronous tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am having issues with many of my events (maybe 20%) not getting recorded in Google Analytics.  These are all events called with onclick on an image button that posts a form.  I believe that the code isn't running fast enough to submit the events to Google before the browser moves on to the next page.

What I would like to do is check the state of _gaq's queue and make sure there are no pending events before completing my Javascript.

_gaq seems a little cryptic to me, but it does have an exposed property - u.  I've been testing in Chrome with a simple command of:

```
console.log(_gaq.u);
```

Unfortunately, this always returns 0, even if run immediately after the _gaq.push command.  Of course, Chrome always seems to get the events sent to Google before the post fires, so I'm not sure if I even can debug in Chrome, since I can't replicate the problem.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the count of pending items in the queue from _gaq?  Is _gaq.u the appropriate property?  I would like to do something a little more elegant than just throwing a 100 or 200 ms wait on all my events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_gaq` has 2 stages.

First, when its an array, before `ga.js` has loaded, its a queue of either function names with their arguments, or actual functions.

Then, when `ga.js` loads, it gets converted into a special object, the queue is processed (the functions are called), and all subsequent `_gaq.push()` calls immediately execute what they're passed.

At the time that it is still a queue, `_gaq` is just a normal JavaScript array. So, you can access the number of items that are waiting to be processed with `_gaq.length`. Once the queue is processed, there is no way the queue.

The `onclick` race condition issue is a common one. Many people like to get around it by preventing the default action, doing their event track, and then setting a short-timespanned setTimeout that completes the original action.

My preference is to not compromise the user experience just for analytics (and I do this for a living.) So, my solution is to use `onmousedown` and `onkeydown` as substitutes (together I refer to them as `preclick`. It eliminates the race condition, with only minimal false positives, which is good enough for web analytics, which is about approximate models, not scientific accuracy.

Here's an example in jQuery:

```
$.fn.preclick = function(param) {
    if (!param) {
        return this.trigger("mousedown");
    }
    return this.one("keydown.preclick mousedown.preclick", function(e) {
        if (e.type === "mousedown" || e.which === 13) {
            param.apply(this);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried using the synchronous code to avoid this situation.  I am using the asynchronous code for page tracking, but all events that were occurring on button clicks were coded using the synchronous version.

I tested this in Chrome and it worked fine (despite the constant deprecation warnings for using _getTracker).  Deploying it and running it for a couple of days has resulted in absolutely no change in behavior - 20 - 25% of events are not being captured.

Any idea why the synchronous code didn't solve this problem?  I haven't done an analysis yet to see if there's a browser-specific issue.

Comment: Also, yahelc, have you tested your `onmousedown` and `onkeydown` events in idevices, specifically iPad?

Comment: @bkgraham yep. Check out Apple's docs; it works fine http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: We ended up adding a wait.  No choice.  We also check the request's user agent and extend the wait for Safari - 100 ms is not enough time for Safari to run the JS.