# Firing the Facebook Conversion Pixel

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, analytics

I'm still pretty new to Javascript, but I was wondering what would be the best way to fire the Facebook conversion pixel (below) without actually loading a "confirmation"/"Thank You" page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=XXXXXXXXXX&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
```

Facebook says that we should plug this into our "Thank You pages" that visitors see after they convert (fill out a form, make a purchase, etc). However, some of our forms are popups or forms on sidebars next to content that we don't want readers to be directed away from by a confirmation page.

With Google Analytics, I can create an "invisible" pageview by firing _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); code that can tell GA that it should count that invisible pageview as a goal completion.

Is there something similar to that that's general enough to tell my site to fire the FB pixel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: I've updated my code as what I had mentioned previously did not work. Thanks to @Flambino to pointing out.

This is my revised answer using a pixel rather than a script to pass the conversion pixel. I reference the [How to track a Google Adwords conversion onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2082129/167996) SO post:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function facebookConversionPixel(fb_pixel, fb_value){
    var image = new Image(1,1); 
    image.src = "//www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=" + fb_pixel + "&amp;value=" + fb_value + "&amp;currency=USD";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="facebookConversionPixel(123456,0.00);">FBCONV</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks!

Is it right to assume that removing this portion of the original pixel

'<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=XXXXXXXXXX&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>'

means that even though the Facebook pixel javascript is loaded on every pageview when the <head> section is loaded, it won't actually be fired until the onclick code is activated by a click?

Comment: That is correct. I removed `<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="facebook.com/…; /></noscript>` as it's a fallback for visitors with javascript turned off. In our case, if your visitor does have js turned off, this tag will simply not fire. However, including it within a function simply defeats its purpose.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this won't work. `fb_params` is a local variable (unlike in the original, where it's a global). Since it's local, the script that's inserted won't be able to access it, and won't be able to read the `pixel_id`. This will just fetch a script that won't do anything, as there's no ID for it to read.

Comment: @Flambino Thanks for point this out. I'm still learning, but what you said made sense. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that looks better (I took the liberty of editing it a little). And it's pinging `offsite_event`-script directly, rather than fetching some JS that _then_ pings that script, so less overhead. You may want to do some `encodeURIComponent()` on the values before using them in the URL, but it shouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: Nice trick to avoid `CORS` or `jsonp execution` warnings. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Is there anyway to trigger the pixel without using Image constructor? Just wondering why we setting the url to image src? Is there no other way?

Answer (score 8):

From the FB docs ["How to track in-page events"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#in-page-events):

After the base code snippet is installed, you can track in-page actions, such as clicks on a button, by making a _fbq.push('track') call for the conversion pixel through registering different event handlers on an HTML DOM element. For example:

```
function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
  var cd = {};
  cd.value = val;
  cd.currency = cny;
  _fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', cd]);
}
<button onClick="trackConversionEvent('10.00','USD');" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Just move the entire original code into the event of your choice. Then just change 1 part of the code. The thing you will have to do is make the `fb_param` global instead of local.

See below at the comment

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    window.fb_param = {}; // must be global by adding `window.`
    fb_param.pixel_id = '123456789';
    fb_param.value = '0.00';
    fb_param.currency = 'USD';
    (function(){
        var fpw = document.createElement('script'); fpw.async = true; fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
        var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar kind of issue and I would like to run multiple adds to track pixels codes and some reason I was not able to track. What I did is that, in the current page I have added pixel code in footer and javascript function 
to call when my ajax button get submitted.

First refer to Facebook documentation page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#multi-conv-events

How to track Multiple Conversion Events

After the base code snippet is installed, you can track multiple conversions within the same web page by making multiple _fbq.push('track') calls for each conversion pixel ids. For example:

```
_fbq.push(['track','<pixel_id1>',{'value':'10.00','currency':'USD'}]);
_fbq.push(['track','<pixel_id2>']);
```

How to track In-Page Events

After the base code snippet is installed, you can track in-page actions, such as clicks on a button, by making a _fbq.push('track') call for the conversion pixel through registering different event handlers on an HTML DOM element. For example:

```
function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
  var cd = {};
  cd.value = val;
  cd.currency = cny;
 _fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', cd]);
 }
 <button onClick="trackConversionEvent('10.00','USD');" />
```

Also, add the facebook pixel tracking code chrome addon and refer the facebook pixel helper page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-troubleshooting

See my below solution/answer

Facebook tracking code in the current page
     
     
     (function() {
     var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
      if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
     }
     })();
     window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
     window._fbq.push(['track', 'yourid', {'value':'1.00','currency':'USD'}]);

```
  <!-- Facebook Conversion -->
  <script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
   var fbds = document.createElement('script');
  fbds.async = true;
  fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
  _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  })();
  window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
  window._fbq.push(['track', 'yourid', {'value':'1.00','currency':'USD'}]);
  </script>
```

And the javascript code to call when ajax form submit or button click

```
 <script>
 function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
 var cd = {};
 cd.value = val;
 cd.currency = cny;
 _fbq.push(['track', 'yourid1', cd]);
 _fbq.push(['track', 'yourid1', cd]);

 }
</script>
```

and the call the function when ajax called

```
jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({

   type:"POST",

   data: $(form).serialize(),

   url:"process.php",

    success: function() {
    **trackConversionEvent**('1.00','USD');
   }
   ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has updated their pixels, so I created my own custom function to call that will dynamically put the parameters together to submit to Facebook.

Step 1. On every page, make sure [you've initialised your pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/using-the-pixel#get) in the **head** element of the page.

Step 2. Add this custom function I created (it's a bit verbose as it is the first draft, so I'm sure there are ways to optimise it for your benefit).

```
triggerFacebookPixel: function(type, price, product_id, product_name, product_category, num_items) {
    //See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-events/v2.8#events for documentation
    //type = "ViewContent"|"AddToCart"|"Search"|"AddToWishlist"|"InitiateCheckout"|"AddPaymentInfo"|"Purchase"|"Lead"|"CompleteRegistration"
    //product_id = Numeric Product ID. String or Integer accepted for single product events, or an array of integers for multiple products.
    //price = Decimal/Float number of individual product's price or total price paid in conversion, or the user's status for 'CompleteRegistration'
    //product_name = Optional. String of individual product's name or string of search query
    //product_category = Optional. String of product category, hierarchy's accepted. E.g. "Clothing > Shirts > Men's > T-Shirts"
    //num_items = Optional. Total number of products.
    var data = {
        value: typeof(price) == 'string' ? parseFloat(price) : price,
        currency: 'USD'
    }
    switch (type) {
        case 'Search':
            data.content_ids = product_id;
            data.search_string = product_name;
            if (product_category !== undefined && product_category != '') {
                data.content_category = product_category;
            }
            break;
        case 'Lead':
            data.content_name = product_name;
            data.content_category = product_category;
            break;
        case 'CompleteRegistration':
            data.status = product_id;
            data.content_name = product_name;
            break;
        default:
            //Product Specific Calls
            //ViewContent|AddToCart|AddToWishlist|InitiateCheckout|AddPaymentInfo|Purchase
            if (num_items == 1) {
                data.content_ids = [typeof(product_id) == 'string' ? parseInt(product_id) : product_id];
                data.content_category = product_category;
                data.content_name = product_name;
            } else {
                data.content_ids = product_id;
            }
            //"num_items" is only a parameter used in these two types
            if (type == 'InitiateCheckout' || type == 'Purchase') {
                data.num_items = num_items
            }
            //"content_type" is only a parameter used in these three types
            if (type == 'Purchase' || type == 'AddToCart' || type == 'ViewContent') {
                data.content_type = 'product';
            }
            break;
    }
    fbq('track', type, data);
}
```

Step 3. Call that function with the appropriate parameters.

For your thank you pop-up after a purchase, the pixel is fired differently if the user purchases 1 item as opposed to multiple items. Basically, Facebook accepts parameters for product names and categories if it's just one product, but doesn't accept those parameters if it's multiple products.

For the following examples, here is some sample product data of a user **purchasing 1 item**:

- Product Name: "My Super Awesome T-Shirt"
- Product ID: 182
- Product Category: "Clothing > Shirts > T-Shirts"
- Total amount user paid (including shipping/handling & tax): $10.84

And here's the function you'd call on the confirmation:

```
triggerFacebookPixel('Purchase', 10.84, 182, 'My Super Awesome T-Shirt', 'Clothing > Shirts > T-Shirts', 1);
```

When a user **purchases multiple items**, the pixel handles it differently, excluding the product names and categories and only sending their ID's. So let's pretend our user purchased these two items:

- Product ID's: 182 and 164 (the shirt and something else)
- Total amount user paid (including shipping/handling & tax): $24.75

This is how you'd use the function:

```
triggerFacebookPixel('Purchase', 24.75, [182, 164], '', '', 2);
```

For other [standard events as defined by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-events/v2.8#events) regarding products, you can use this same function for "ViewContent", "AddToCart", "AddToWishlist", "InitiateCheckout", and "AddPaymentInfo". Just change "Purchase" to any of those key words in your call.

The other events aren't necessarily related to products: "Lead", "Search", and "Complete Registration". You can still use this function for those key words like this.

Example: user **searched** for "blue shirts":

```
triggerFacebookPixel('Search', 0, [], 'blue shirts');
```

If you want to pass a product category in the user search function, you can pass that as a string at the end. I can't think of a use-case scenario where you'd know what category the user is searching for. Unless you used this in the event that the product appears in the search results and the user clicked on it from the search page. That might be what this function is actually for but the documentation isn't quite clear on that. If that's the case for you, then simply change the 0 and empty array to the actual values (price and product ID, respectively) of the product that was clicked on from the search results page, and add its category as a string as the last parameter after the search string.

Example: user **submitted a form that signed them up to your newsletter**:

```
triggerFacebookPixel('CompleteRegistration', 0, 'Signed Up', 'Newsletter');
```

Facebook's documentation states that "CompleteRegistration" should be used when a registration form is completed, e.g. complete subscription/signup for a service. The "Signed Up" string is the "status" parameter and the "Newsletter" string is the "content_name" parameter.

Example: user submitted a form that signed them up for a free 30-day trial of some service you offer (so they are now a **lead**), where the name of the service is "Free 30-Day Trial Service" and it's in the sub-category "Free Trials" under the category "My Services":

```
triggerFacebookPixel('Lead', 0, 'Free 30-Day Trial Service', 'My Services > Free Trials');
```

Facebook's documentation states that "Lead" is when a sign up is completed, e.g. click on pricing, signup for trial. I assumed that the name of the service is the parameter "content_name" and the category of the service is the "content_category" parameter.