# How to detect if tracking tags fired with javascript? (Facebook and Google on Shopify)

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm hosting my store on a third party (Shopify) which takes care of sending event data to Facebook Pixel and Google. In some scenarios I would like to do a redirect from a temporary page; however, my redirect occurs faster than sending event data.

Is there any way to detect if Facebook and Google tracking tags fired (or got blocked by AdBlock?) and execute code after that?

Keep in mind that I cannot modify Shopify tracking tags integration, I can only build something "on top of it."

I tried tips that can be easily found on Stack Overflow, like [Firing the Facebook Conversion Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261604/firing-the-facebook-conversion-pixel), but most of them:

1. assume that I have control over tracking tags integration; or
2. do not take adblocks into account

Answer (score 0):

You can try to intercept AJAX request (check how to on google) and redirect only when you've intercepted the XHR calls of your trackers (by intercept i mean catch it - check it - raise it back, not stop it)

And in addition put your redirection function in a setTimeout to force redirection after X seconds in case of the tracking link as been blocked.